# Itunes Connect App transfer

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, itunes-store

> You can only transfer
>   apps that aren’t using Passbook IDs, certificates, or notifications.

Everytime when I try to transfer my app, I get the above message in iTunesConnect.

I have not used any passbook ID , certificate or notifications in my app.

Any help or suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, the easiest way if you run into problems to call up iTunes Connect telephone support.  Someone can help you do it over the phone.

> U.S. and Canada English
>   +1 (800) 633-2152 Toll-free from the U.S. and Canada.
>
> Other English
>   +1 (408) 974-4897 International charges may apply.

Comment: Yeah , i already did that . I called them and they replied "please go through the app trasfer FAQ , you will get answer there " . There is no reply of my answer in FAQ

Comment: You're KIDDING.  That is absolutely ridiculous.  They didn't actually give you the answer but told you to go look for it?

Comment: From answer I means to say : They told me for my question I will get my answer in FAQ section :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the app settings in apple developer. While you might not actually coded anything, you might have ticked the wrong box when you set the profile. If you did, that's might explain it.

An alternative, which you'll need to check with apple (sorry), would be to rename the app. Once done, then you might be allowed to use the name in the new entity.

If the app has been submitted for app store review, or if you have released it in the past, you might need to submit another copy in the new name. If/when approved, the old name, at least in theory, should become 'available'. Then, change the code signing, and submit via the new entity.

Good luck!